# GloVe - uneven encoding vector

Tags: python, nlp, word-embedding

I just downloaded [glove.840B.300d.zip](http://nlp.stanford.edu/data/glove.840B.300d.zip)

and noticed that not all elements are encoded to the same vector size. In particular

```
path = '../path_to_glove/file.txt'
read_file = open(path, 'r', encoding="utf-8")
for i, el in enumerate(read_file):
    if len(el.split())>301:
        print(i)
        print(len(el.split()))
```

produced:

```
52343
303
```

Is this a bug or I am doing something wrong?

Comment: Please also print(el). Basically, every word has the same dimension. Therefore, split seems to be splitting the word. If this is the case, just take the last 300 entries...

Comment: @user3640029 This is very good idea. I think things like '. . .' or any expression with space inside cause trouble. I am just surprised that there is no official guidelines on how to use GloVe.